# How do I convert a datetime.date object into a time.struct_time object?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a python script which I need to compare two dates. I have a list dates as time.struct_time objects which I need to compare to a few datetime.date objects.

How do I convert the datetime.date objects into a time.struct_time objects? Or can I just use them as is for comparison?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using [`date.timetuple()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple). From the Python docs:

> Return a [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time) such as
>   returned by `time.localtime()`. The
>   hours, minutes and seconds are 0, and
>   the DST flag is -1. `d.timetuple()` is
>   equivalent to
>   `time.struct_time((d.year, d.month,
>   d.day, 0, 0, 0, d.weekday(), yday,
>   -1))`, where `yday = d.toordinal() - date(d.year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1` is
>   the day number within the current year
>   starting with 1 for January 1st.

Answer (score 1):

Example for converting date objects to time.struct_time objects :

```
#### Import the necessary modules
>>> dt = date(2008, 11, 10)
>>> time_tuple = dt.timetuple()
>>> print repr(time_tuple)
'time.struct_time(tm_year=2008, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0,     
 tm_wday=0, tm_yday=315, tm_isdst=-1)'
```

Refer this link for more examples: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-datetime-time-conversions/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for the [time Python module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time), which indicates that you can use [calendar.timegm](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) or [time.mktime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) to convert the [time.struct_time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object to seconds since the epoch (which function you use depends on whether your struct_time is in a timezone or in UTC time). You can then use [datetime.datetime.time](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on the other object, and compare in seconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` from "datetime". It has various attributes and the respective data can be fetched using directives. See [this cheat-sheet](https://strftime.org/) for a full list of directives that can be used with the `strftime method`. Note that the directives shall be passed to `strftime` as a string in single quotes.

Example:

```
import datetime as dt
today = dt.datetime.today()
print(today.strftime('%H')) #prints hour 0-23
print(today.strftime('%m')) #prints month number 1-12
print(today.strftime('%M')) #prints minute 0-59
```